# We are investigating increased API error rates in the us-east-1 Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to using Opscentre. I got this Alarm saying

"Issue detected for EC2 infrastructure"
Description : "We are investigating increased API error rates in the us-east-1 Region"

I Don't  have any idea of what is it and not able to get a clear description of what this issue about.
Can anyone help me out.

Comment: It means they have an issue that they are working on, so in case you see something weird happening you know that it's because of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will just be AWS events alerting you that there is an ongoing incident involved in that region.

You can view more information in your [personal health dashboard](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/technology/personal-health-dashboard/).

Comment: So is it anything wrong on our side or its AWS responsibility

Comment: This is all AWS responsibility :)

Comment: Thanks for you response . That was really helpful.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)